# C# Overload Error Message

Tags: c#, sharepoint, new-operator, overloading, arguments

So I've been trying to use this piece of code below to try and upload an image into the SharePoint image library.

```
static NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password, domain);
static ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteURL);
static Web site = clientContext.Web;
static List list = site.Lists.GetByTitle("Site Images");

private static byte[] StreamFile(string filename)
{
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    // Create a byte array of file stream length
    byte[] ImageData = new byte[fs.Length];
    //Read  block of bytes from stream into the byte array
    fs.Read(ImageData, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
    //Close the File Stream
    fs.Close();
    return ImageData;
}


private static void uploadImage()
{
    String fileName = "Sunset";
    String filePath = "C://Documents and Settings//Desktop//Sample Extracted Pic.jpeg";

    list.RootFolder.Files.Add(fileName, StreamFile(filePath));
}
```

...And everything seems fine (at least within the compiler), until you get to: `list.RootFolder.Files.Add(fileName, StreamFile(fileName));`

The compiler returns an error saying `No overload for method 'Add' takes 2 arguments`, and I understand what it's saying, but I have no idea why I am getting that error. Does anyone have any idea or proposed solutions? All feedback is appreciated.

Comment: Assuming it's an `SPList`, this should work. According to this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms461726.aspx, there is an overload taking 2 arguments, one string and one byte array. Are you sure this is where the error is?

Comment: Sorry, that's the problem, it's not type `SPLIST`. At this moment I can't access the directory on the server to use the microsoft.sharepoint.dll file. Thus I am trying to find an alternative way.

I included some additional variables in my original code.

Comment: Which version of the server are you targeting? WSS 3.0 or SP 2010? Are you using a client SDK or one of the web services directly (such as Lists.asmx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client object model's Add method only has one parameter: **FileCreationInformation**. See this MSDN page for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.filecollection.add.aspx